# Prove $f(x,y) = x+y^2$ is a continuous function

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x,y) = x+y^2$. How do I prove that this is continuous?

I was going to try to take an open set of R, call it V, and show that $g^{-1}(V)$ is open, but I don't know how. Alternatively, could I use an epsilon delta argument? How would that work in this case?

Comment: Hint : the sum of continuous functions is continuous, and if $g(x)$ is continuous then so is $f(x,y)=g(x)$. *

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki Sorry but I still don't get it, can you explain a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki I doubt that the OP is supposed to use that.

Comment: Can you show continuity with sequences? I think this would simplify alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the sum and composition of continuous functions are continuous.

Step 1 : Prove that $g : x \mapsto x$ and $h : y \mapsto y^2$ are continuous functions of one real variable.

Step 2 : Prove that the functions $\pi_1 : (x,y) \mapsto x$ and $\pi_2 : (x,y) \mapsto y$ are continuous.

Step 3 : Note that $f = g \circ \pi_1 + h \circ \pi_2$. Conclude.

Step 1 should be already a known fact, but proving with $\epsilon-\delta$ is a good exercise if you're not familiar with it. Step 2 should be easy as well with $\epsilon-\delta$. All this could be directly proved via a direct $\epsilon-\delta$ argument, but it would be very close to this. Here the steps are just a bit more separate and the proof a little less direct. Let me know if you want me to post more explicit proof.